# 12.04 LTS no sound at all from speakers

Tags: 12.04, sound, soundcard

I have a computer running 12.04 LTS and I have only ever downloaded 12.04 on this PC (I had PuppyLinux but it was from a live CD, and Windows XP Home but it was not activated.)

So when I hit the sound options from the top panel, the only sound option I get for output (to speakers/headphones etc) is the dummy output and I have a soundcard (embedded to the motherboard) and Ubuntu does not pick up the soundcard and I have no sound *at all not even boot* sounds.

PC specs:

- CPU: Intel Xeon (2.40 GHz)
- GPU: I have no idea
- RAM: 4 GB
- mobo: I know its an Intel motherboard
- PSU: 400 watts
- BIOS : 2006 Phoenix BIOS embedded Server BIOS)
- Type of PC or use of PC before I had it: SERVER (as in big business PC built to run 24/7 365 days a year)

Any one got any ideas?

Comment: i dont know how to show my sound card or graphics card using the terminal in ubuntu :l

Comment: Actually I recommend inxi for this. See what is added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I actually cannot recommend the way to install the drivers as far as I even cannot understand the question. The newest driver is called PulseAudio, the oldest driver that is still being used is called Alsa. These are probably the two best drivers. Alsa is still the official Linux driver.

If some day you get the Alsa driver correctly installed and you get no sound at all you can test if your speakers or headphones are not disabled, this is what happened to me.

From the Terminal you download the tool that lets you enable your speakers, type:

sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer

From the main menu call this program and enable your speakers.

Otherwise you can use Synaptic and try to install almost what I did install:

[image]

---

To show information about your system you could do:

```
me@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install inxi
me@ubuntu:~$ inxi -v 7
```

If you don't want to install anything and look for the most known command:

```
me@ubuntu:~$ lspci
```

The most important tools for any user are always the logfiles:

```
me@ubuntu:~$ gnome-system-log
```